# Select case when then multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I write case when then for the following scenario. I keep getting missing keyword error in oracle. Thank you in advance

```
SELECT login_id, 
CASE when login_id = 'Thomas'
Then lastnm as lastname, 
ssn as SocialSecurityNumber 
Else Then 
Secondarylastnm as lastname, 
Secondaryssn as SocialSecurityNumber 
End
from Employees
```

Comment: remove 2nd "then".  Also, the first place to start researching this is reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html#GUID-CA29B333-572B-4E1D-BA64-851FABDBAE96)

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-write you statement as -

```
SELECT login_id, 
       CASE WHEN login_id = 'Thomas'
                 THEN lastnm 
            ELSE Secondarylastnm END as lastname,
       CASE WHEN login_id = 'Thomas'
                 THEN ssn 
            ELSE Secondaryssn END as SocialSecurityNumber 
from Employees
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `union all` to implement your logic.

```
select login_id, lastnm as lastname, ssn as socialsecuritynumber 
from employees
where login_id='thomas'

union all

select login_id, secondarylastnm, secondaryssn
from employees
where login_id<>'thomas';
```